# Embedding a link to google map in the email

Tags: google-maps

In my meeting management application, I am trying to send the meeting location information via mail and in the mail content I would like to place a link to to the google map site, so that the meeting place could be seen on the map.

What would be the best way to construct the **google map url string** (eg. http://maps.google.com/maps?q=address) , for a particular address.

Thanks

Comment: You answered your own question. "`http://maps.google.com/maps?q=...`" works just fine.

Comment: Yeah, but l just wanted to know that, is there any better options :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducing the clutter of arguments to a minimum, this seems to work pretty well:
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=1+infinite+loop,+cupertino,+CA

Comment: If you really want to be minimal, you can omit "/maps" and just write http://maps.google.com?q=1+infinite+loop+cupertino+CA and Google Maps ignores punctuation, so you never need comma and space together.